# <input type="file" /> not showing files path

Tags: html, file, path, file-upload

I have a file uploader but it's not showing the files path (so you can only upload files that are in the same folder)

How can I make it so  show's the files path (desktop/something/yes/dog.swf)

Comment: what kind of file uploader do you have? Does it override the styling of default input with type="file"?

Answer (score 6):

It's getting more common that browsers doesn't reveal the local path where the uploaded file was selected, and this is for most purposes a good thing. If you upload a file to a site you probably don't want any excess information to be sent along, like for example your local user name.

For you as an application developer it should not make any difference. You shouldn't rely on the local path of the file for anything. If you use the local path on the server side also, you open up a horribly wide security hole. Anyone could for example upload a file with the path "c:\windows\explorer.exe", and if you save the file there you are in trouble...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, that's a client side browser issue, and not something you can set in your code.

It's also browser-specific, so we would have to know the browser version to tell how to do it on YOUR browser, and that would do nothing for other people accessing the web site via their browser.

If you want to ask how to set it on your browser, I would recommend that you ask that on the Super-User site. (See the links at the bottom of this page.)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to upload a file from another folder? I've noticed that no path is shown but it still works just fine.