# How to get the full path from browse in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on Rails I have placed a browse button and from that one I will browse files, displaying in that browse input box but I want to get full path from input box while clicking one button(get full path). Here's an example:

```
<input id="browse" type="file" size="45" name="browse" class="input" />
```

Is it possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [<input type="file" /> not showing files path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415950/input-type-file-not-showing-files-path)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only get access to this (on the client side) in IE. Firefox et all strip the path information for security reasons.

Comment: It should be noted that the point of the file input is to *upload a file* and not to reveal information about the filename and directory structure on the client machine (information which is useless in a web context).

Comment: That is indeed true. I can't think of a _legitimate_ reason one would ever need the path information.

Comment: It's for local web applications that use Ruby on Rails